# Windows 8 Audio playing in background

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have read previous posts on this and documents by microsoft but cannot seem to get my app to run Sound in the background. It plays 100% but when ever the app is then suspended the music also stops. I have added "Background Tasks" declarations selecting Audio and my audio tag looks like this

```
<audio id="musicplayr" msAudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" controls="controls"><source src="song.mp3"/> </audio
```

and finally my javascript includes the references to MediaControls

```
var MediaControls = Windows.Media.MediaControl;

        // Add event listeners for the buttons
        MediaControls.addEventListener("playpressed", play, false);
        MediaControls.addEventListener("pausepressed", pause, false);
        MediaControls.addEventListener("playpausetogglepressed", playpausetoggle, false);

        // Add event listeners for the audio element
        document.getElementById("musicplayr").addEventListener("playing", playing, false);
        document.getElementById("musicplayr").addEventListener("paused", paused, false);
        document.getElementById("musicplayr").addEventListener("ended", ended, false);
```

and below in the code i have the event handlers

```
// Define functions that will be the event handlers
function play() {
    document.getElementById("musicplayr").play();
}
function pause() {
    document.getElementById("musicplayr").pause();
}

function playpausetoggle() {
    if(MediaControls.isPlaying === true) {
        document.getElementById("musicplayr").pause();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("musicplayr").play();
    }
}

function playing() {
    Windows.Media.MediaControl.isPlaying = true;
}

function paused() {
    Windows.Media.MediaControl.isPlaying = false;
}

function ended() {
    Windows.Media.MediaControl.isPlaying = false;
}
```

*Note musicplayr is the reference for the html5  tag

Any help appreciated why this is not working?

Comment: Don't see anything obviously wrong with it.  I wonder if this sample works for playing background media http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Playback-Manager-e6526e67/ If it does, it might help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Audio in Windows 8 App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382917/background-audio-in-windows-8-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need an event handler for the stoppressed event. Without any of the four handlers--playpressed, pausepressed, playpausetogglepressed, and stoppressed--background audio won't be enabled. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/winappswithhtml5/thread/2ca0c122-df31-401c-a444-2149dd3e8d68 on the MSDN forums where the same problem was raised.

.Kraig

Comment: You are a genius! :D Going to contact MS to get this fixed in their documentation!

Comment: Thanks for the kind compliment. It helps to have written a book on Win8 apps (Microsoft Press, a free ebook), and for this particular space I sat down directly with the engineers who created the feature. :) And the docs team always appreciates feedback, of any kind.

Comment: Talk about the right man at the right time! :) Thanks again. My app is 100% finished and in the store now. Search MetroTracks in a few days if you want to see results! :)

Comment: I look forward to trying it. I've been looking for a music player that can run on my Surface and play albums from the microSD card I have all my mp3's on. Win8 won't let me add that card to the Music Library, so the built-in Music app won't display its albums.

Comment: Sorry, its not that sort of music player :) but heres the final link http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-GB/app/metrotracks/4dada31f-d6d7-4972-93a3-3e6917eaa896

Comment: Glad to see it made it into the Store. I'll check it out anyway when I have a chance.

Comment: Had a chance to check it out--nicely done! I do have some feedback but I'll contact you about that directly.

Comment: Also ensure that event names are all lowercase!