# Preventing Sleep on Surface Pro

Tags: windows-8

I want to create an application that can run in the background, with the screen off, but prevent the Surface Pro from sleeping.  Essentially, I have an audio book player, but as soon as I turn off the screen to listen to the audio book and attempt to save power, the Surface goes to sleep.  In fact, the only way I know how to prevent sleep is to keep the display on, but I explicitly don't want to do that as I want to save power.  Because of this, the [DisplayRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx) is not a good solution for this problem.

Comment: lol, I slightly misunderstood the title... the [old surface table](http://cloudfront3.bostinno.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Microsoft-Surface-pic.jpg) is something I could easily imagine falling asleep on :)

Comment: Hah, best misread on SO yet!

Answer (score 0):

Are you essentially trying to do background audio, then? To enable that, you need to make sure you register four event handlers with the Media Control object, and enable background audio in the manifest. I just [answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783618/windows-8-audio-playing-in-background/14784613#comment20843170_14784613), and more info on background audio can be found in the docs ([XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx) | HTML/JS). I cover the topic for JS also in CHapter 10 of [my book](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook).

It's helpful to understand that background audio is a special class of background tasks that lets more of the device sleep than if you just kept the entire app running all the time. It will allow you to turn off the screen (directly event), and have the audio still respond to volume controls and play/pause controls (as on the Surface touch keyboard).

.Kraig

Comment: Not quite. I actually want to make a generic power management app, which allows me to keep the device awake while _other_ applications are open.  The application inspiring this is Audible, which shuts off just as I hit the power button to turn the screen off/close the flap to turn the screen off. I'd like to make a background process which keeps the device awake for other applications that don't have this functionality built in.

Comment: Also, I think you just got at least one more reader for your book!

Comment: In this case Audible would have to implement background audio support. Windows store app can not keep another windows store app from being suspended.

Comment: Audible plays in the background just fine; but it doesn't stop the device from sleeping.  I don't think Audible lacks the background audio support; it lacks the power management support to stop the device from sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Say, you want to write a clock app, you would want to accomplish the same thing, right? This blog post walks you through the process: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 I wish I had written it.

Comment: Jerry, this link is nice, but I'm having trouble narrowing down exactly what I want.  Perhaps I have some misconceptions, let me try and explain a little more in detail: I want to write an app that allows the screen of the surface to turn off, but all other applications continue running.  I understand that I can get my process to continue in the background, but I want to create a utility to emulate giving these permissions to _other_ processes, so the easiest first solution is to simply not go to sleep when the lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

That button doesn't actually turn the screen off. What it does is tells the system to sleep, which turns off the screen as part of its routine.

You can Google a program called 'nircmd.exe', and after downloading it and placing it in your Windows folder you can use the command 'C:\Windows\nircmd.exe monitor off' to make a shortcut on your desktop or such.
It's a bit finicky to keep it off (closing the cover turns the screen back on, for some reason), but it works. You could also set your power options to turn the screen off after only a minute of idle.

I think Surface Pro has another issue where leaving it sit for a minute will automatically send it into sleep mode, but having media playing might make it work normally.
You can also make sure your power options are set to the most-possible savings, and it should reach as little as 6 watts of drain (possibly six hours of such reading).