# win 8.1 Html audio continue play after app switched

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8.1

I was wondering how i could let my Windows 8.1 App continue to play my music when the app runs in the background, It's a JS Windows 8.1 Store App.

and just an Audio HTML Tag:

`<audio id="player" controls src="/1.mp3"></audio>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by he following,

A background audio declaration must be in the app manifest.
In HTML this can be done as,

```
 <audio msAudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" controls="controls"> 
<source src="song.mp3"/> 
 </audio>
```

The javascript equivalent of the above

```
 function PlayAudio () 
 {
    // Create new audio tag for "BackgroundCapableMedia" class
    if(!audtag) 
    {
      audtag = document.createElement('audio');
      audtag.setAttribute("id", "audtag");
      audtag.setAttribute("controls", "true");
      audtag.setAttribute("msAudioCategory", "backgroundcapablemedia");
      audtag.setAttribute("src", "song.mp3");
      document.getElementById("scenario1Output").appendChild(audtag);
      audtag.load();
    }
    }
```

Comment: hmm for some reason Visual Studio didn't recognize the msAudioCategory Atribute. and it doesn't work..

Comment: Did you try that with javascript??

Comment: You can find example for running audio in background at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Playback-Manager-e6526e67

Comment: This a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783618/windows-8-audio-playing-in-background

Comment: yea i know something changed in 8.1 for the background running of apps, i'm currently watching the MSDN Code.